# Object of type 'map' has no len() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-length

I have a problem with Python 3. I got Python 2.7 code and at the moment I am trying to update it. I get the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

at this part:

```
str(len(seed_candidates))
```

Before I initialized it like this:

```
seed_candidates = map(modify_word, wordlist)
```

So, can someone explain me what I have to do?

(EDIT: Previously this code example was wrong because it used `set` instead of `map`. It has been updated now.)

Comment: It works for me. Post a full example that demonstrates the problem. You didn't even call `map` anywhere in the code above.

Comment: This is currently the top result from Google and the current question doesn't really have a great example of `map`, so I'm going to edit the question somewhat drastically and change the code the OP originally had. I imagine OP missed out something back when the question was first asked two years ago. Feel free to revert if anyone objects

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In Python 3, `map` returns a map object not a `list`:

```
>>> L = map(str, range(10))
>>> print(L)
<map object at 0x101bda358>
>>> print(len(L))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

You can convert it into a list then get the length from there:

```
>>> print(len(list(L)))
10
```

Comment: I think there is a canonical question/answer for this. The above question is a duplicate.

Comment: I think list(L) will make the iterator run to the end, and that will make that iterator won't be useful again(unless you reproduce that iterator on purpose)

Answer (score 11):

While the accepted answer might work for the OP, there are some things to learn here, because **sometimes you can't find the length** even with doing the OP's `map(modify_word, wordlist)` casted into list and checking the length with `len(list(map(modify_word, wordlist)))`. **You can't because sometimes the length is infinite**.

For example let's consider the following generator that lazy calculate all the naturals:

```
def naturals():
    num = 0
    while True:
        yield num
        num +=1
```

And let's say I want to get the square of each of those, that is,

```
doubles = map(lambda x: x**2, naturals())
```

Note that this is a completely legit use of map function, and will work, and will allow you to use next() function on the `doubles` variable:

```
>>> doubles = map(lambda x: x**2, naturals())
>>> next(doubles)
0
>>> next(doubles)
1
>>> next(doubles)
4
>>> next(doubles)
9
...
```

But, what if we try to cast it into a list? Obviously python can't know if we are trying to iterate through a never-ending iterator. So if we'll try to cast an instance of this mapObject to a list, python will *try and keep trying* and will get stuck on an infinite loop.

**So when you cast to list, you should first make sure you know your map object will indeed yield finite number of elements.**