# object of type 'map' has no len() containing Float

Tags: python

I am executing following lines of code.
Vector file is produced using word2vec.

I am getting an error on this line:

```
vector = map(float, fields)
length_of_vectors = len(vector)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

How can i resolve this error?

I have tried converting

```
vector = map(float, fields)
```

to

```
vector = list(map(float, fields))
```

but it gives following error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

```
with io.open(vec_file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':
            continue
        word = line[0:line.index(' ')]
        rest = line[line.index(' ') + 1:]
        fields = rest.split(' ')
        vector = map(float, fields)
        length_of_vectors = len(vector)
        word_vector_dictionary[word] = vector
f.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object of type 'map' has no len() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982858/object-of-type-map-has-no-len-in-python-3)

Comment: What is `fields` containing?

Comment: @Sayse If you read, they already tried that. Their actual issue is they are trying to convert strings to floats. Probably worth closing for a different reason though

Comment: @Chris_Rands - I did read, they also state near the top "How can I resolve this error?" as well as it being the questions title, the rest of the question should be a seperate question which is no doubt also a duplicate as the file probably contains data that isn't a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gives error because you give map obj to len(),
If you looking for length of each tuple then try this one

```
def lenfun(i):
    return len(i)

length_of_vectors = map(lenfun,list_of_tuple)
print(length_of_vectors)
```

error convert string to float :

in a given code 'fields' is a string,but in line -> vector = map(float, fields) you convert string 'fields' to float 'fields'(containing numbers,letters),letters CANNOT be converted into float