# TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() when trying to insert a CSV into an SQL Server database in Python 3

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, csv, pyodbc

So I'm trying to get a CSV file into an SQL Server,

**sample csv file**

```
STUFF,NAME,A DATE,A TIME,ANOTHER DATE,ANOTHER TIME,A NUMBER Bananas
John Smith,2019-11-20,17:00,2019-11-20,20:00,3 Apples,Jane Doe,2019-11-07,17:00,2019-11-07,23:00,6
```

here's how I'm trying to do it (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260488/importing-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-python)):

```
import csv  
import pyodbc  

thecsv = 'iamacsvfile.csv'

print('connecting')
drivr = "SQL Server"
servr = "1.2.3.4"
db = "testdata"
username = "user"
password = "thepassword"
my_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};SERVER={};DATABASE={};UID={};PWD={}'.format(drivr,servr,db,username,password))

my_cursor = my_cnxn.cursor()

def insert_records(table, thecsv, my_cursor, my_cnxn):

    with open(thecsv) as csvfile:
        csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(csvFile)
        headers = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
        insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES ({})' .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?'))
        for row in csvFile:
            values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), row)  
            my_cursor.execute(insert, values) 
            my_cnxn.commit()


table = 'dbo.iamthetable'
mycsv = thecsv 
insert_records(table, mycsv, my_cursor, my_cnxn)
my_cursor.close()
```

Error message:

> insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES ({})' .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?'))
>   TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

I've seen some similar examples of this type of error (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982858/object-of-type-map-has-no-len-in-python-3)) but I'm not sure how the solutions apply to this particular usage case.  Can anyone assist?

(by the way if this entire code block is bad I'm open to a completely different method of doing the same, but haven't found anything that works yet)

Comment: i think it's better you put sample csv file as well, it's helpful. Also better you can put `print(values)` inside the for loop to check what's going on.

Comment: `STUFF,NAME,A DATE,A TIME,ANOTHER DATE,ANOTHER TIME,A NUMBER
Bananas,John Smith,2019-11-20,17:00,2019-11-20,20:00,3
Apples,Jane Doe,2019-11-07,17:00,2019-11-07,23:00,6` etc

Comment: Try `list(map((lambda x: x.strip()), header))` instead of `map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)`. Basically everytime you get a `map`, convert to list since map has no len method.

Comment: @Sha `print(values)` inside the for loop is a great idea but is not working as the program doesn't get that far.

Comment: @fizzybear okay a new error: `my_cursor.execute(insert, values)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 7 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')`

Comment: have a look on [pyodbc/issues](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/552)

Comment: @Sha I don't see how that applies.  I thought that `insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES ({})' .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?'))` dynamically covers this?  I mean, obviously I'm wrong, but adding their params line didn't work for me.  I don't see how it relates.

Comment: @fizzybear In which case there is practically no reason to use `map()`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your issues are caused by the fact that with modern versions of Python (i.e., Python_3), [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a map *object* which is an iterable, not a list. Consequently,

```python
import csv

with open('C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/foo.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(csvFile)
    print(type(header))  # <class 'list'>
    print(len(header))  # 3
    headers_map = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
    print(type(headers_map))  # <class 'map'>
    try:
        print(len(headers_map))
    except TypeError as e:
        print(str(e))  # object of type 'map' has no len()
    headers_list = list(headers_map)
    print(len(headers_list))  # 3
```

Similarly, if you do something like

```python
values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), row)
my_cursor.execute(insert, values)
```

and get an error like

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 7 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

that's because `values` is a single `<class 'map'>` object, where pyodbc is expecting a `list`, `tuple`, or `Row`. So, define `values` as

```python
values = list(map((lambda x: x.strip()), row))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Progress!  Error message has changed:   `my_cursor.execute(insert, values)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'TYPE'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'DATE'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'TIME'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`

Comment: Now works - thank you!  The error above was generated because my header row in the CSV didn't exactly match the header row in the SQL table.